# UILabel doesn't display attributed text

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am setting attributed text from code. The `infoLabel` is configured in storyboard with font family and size. The `infoLabel` contains 3 lines of text.

Here is how it should look like:

[image: Labels with 3 lines of text. Some parts of it coloured]

What code is producing:

[image: Label with text: 78 days{}{}...]

```
let daysCount: Int = 78
let weight: Double = -3.8
let fitness: Int = 44 // Percent

var daysWord = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("days", comment: "Comparison label line 1"))
if daysCount == 1 {
    daysWord = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("day", comment: "Comparison label line 1"))
}
let firstLine = NSAttributedString(string: "\(daysCount) \(daysWord)")

let weightString = NSLocalizedString("\(weight) kg", comment: "Comparison label line 2")
let weightAttributes: [String : Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.geGreenyBlue]
let attrubutedWeight = NSAttributedString(string: weightString, attributes: weightAttributes)
let secondLine = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("weight: \(attrubutedWeight)", comment: "Comparison label line 2"))

let thirdLine = NSAttributedString(string: "")
infoLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "\(firstLine)\n \(secondLine)\n \(thirdLine)")
```

When I set text in Storyboard with single dark grey color it looks good but then when I change it with the code it adds curly braces to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have a lot of issue. You are not setting the `NSAttributedString` properly also at last you are not even properly combining the multiple `NSAttributedString`. It should be like this way.

```
let daysCount: Int = 78
let weight: Double = -3.8
let fitness: Int = 44 // Percent

var daysWord = "days"
if daysCount == 1 {
    daysWord = "day"
}

let firstLine = NSAttributedString(string: "\(daysCount) \(daysWord)")

//For Weight
let weightAttrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "weight: ")
let weightAttributes: [String : Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor. geGreenyBlue]
let attrubutedWeight = NSAttributedString(string: "\(weight) kg", attributes: weightAttributes)

//For Fitness
let fitnessAttrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "fitness: ")
let fitnessAttributes: [String : Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor. geGreenyBlue]
let attrubutedFitness = NSAttributedString(string: "+\(fitness)%", attributes: fitnessAttributes)

//Now Combine all the attributed with \n
let combineAttr = NSMutableAttributedString()
combineAttr.append(firstLine)
combineAttr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
combineAttr.append(weightAttrStr)
combineAttr.append(attrubutedWeight)

combineAttr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
combineAttr.append(fitnessAttrStr)
combineAttr.append(attrubutedFitness)

//Now set textAligment to center
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center
let attributes: [String : Any] = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph]
combineAttr.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: combineAttr.string.characters.count))

//Now set the combine attributedString to label
infoLabel.attributedText = combineAttr
```

Comment: Nirav, you mean accept? Don't need to, it stays accepted even if you edit it. Thanks for you answer, obviously I needed to make some edits but you solved my main issue, all I need is to call `append()`.

Comment: @borisy i'm saying is check the edited answer, because I have edited answer after I posted answer. So it contains new changes. Not about the accepting answer, because I know you have already accepted my answer.

Comment: @user28434 I don't get your comment.

Comment: Oh rest assured I did check it, Stack Overflow let's you know when answer is updated, if you pay attention.